# UIPageControl advancing more than one page - is there a possibility?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uipagecontrol

Are there any alternatives for UIPageControl which allows to move directly from first page, to, for example, fifth one?

If no - is there possibility to catch a tap from specific dot and highlight it manually?

I have a UIView with UIWebView inside and I am trying to show in it website which number is choosed with UIPageControl.

Answer (score 3):

No. The [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006781-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) clearly says that, **"The page control advances only one page in either direction".** You have to create your own view with the dots and implement the functinality you are looking for.

Comment: I found crafty alternative...https://github.com/honcheng/SliderPageControl-for-iOS

Comment: Good. Glad if that helps you.